# Run a Windows/Mac/Linux command from Flutter and read stdout

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, executable

I am working on a new product, and I have developed a flutter application using Flutter Blue Plus for connectivity to a custom piece of hardware I designed. FBP currently only supports iOS and Android. Even though it is 2023, integrated BLE for Desktops is still a bit underdeveloped and I don't want to write platform specific BLE code yet. The solution is to use a USB Dongle that I have used in the past, which has the full stack and all the hardware to work on any OS with USB access (BLED112 by Silicon Labs). The customers will be required to buy the dongle for $15 until BLE support for desktops mature. I did this before and it was fine.

My question is how do I run an executable from Flutter, and read all of the standard output, without blocking?

I plan on using a simple Python script that interfaces to the dongle with the serial port and spits out GAP and GATT data in real time. I want to launch the Python script from Flutter when Linux/Windows/macOS is detected.

I want to make sure I am going down the correct path with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use [process_run](https://pub.dev/packages/process_run) package.

```
final shell = Shell();
await shell.run('''

# Display dart version
dart --version

# Display pub version
flutter doctor

''');
```